# SwiftUI: Synchronise 2 Animation Functions (CAMediaTimingFunction and Animation.timingCurve)

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I was using `CAMediaTimingFunction` (for a window) and `Animation.timingCurve` (for the content) with the **same Bézier curve and time** to deal with the resizing. However, there can be a very small time difference and therefore it caused the window to flicker irregularly. Just like this (GitHub repository: http://github.com/E8D08F/DVD-Player-Components ; [original design](https://dribbble.com/shots/14674250-Video-Player-Light) by 7ahang):

[image: The Shaking Panel]

Red background indicates the whole window, while green background indicates the content. As you can see, the red background is visible at certain points during the animation, which means that the content is **sometimes smaller** than the window, so it generates extra small spaces and causes unwanted shaking.

In `AppDelegate.swift`, I used a custom `NSWindow` class for the main window and overrode `setContentSize()`:

```swift
class AnimatableWindow: NSWindow {
    var savedSize: CGSize = .zero

    override func setContentSize(_ size: NSSize) {
        if size == savedSize { return }
        savedSize = size

        NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup { context in
            context.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0, 0, 0.58, 1.00) // Custom Bézier curve
            context.duration = animationTime // Custom animation time
            animator().setFrame(NSRect(origin: frame.origin, size: size), display: true, animate: true)
        }
    }
}
```

In `ContentView.swift`, the main structure (simplified):

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showsDrawer: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            SecondaryAdjusters() // Left panel
            
            HStack {
                Drawer() // Size-changing panel
                    .frame(width: showsDrawer ? 175 : 0, alignment: .trailing)
                
                DrawerBar() // Right bar
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation(Animation.timingCurve(0, 0, 0.58, 1.00, duration: animationTime)) { // The same Bézier curve and animation time
                            showsDrawer.toggle()
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The animated object is the size-changing `Drawer()` in the middle. I suppose that it is because the **different frame rate** of two methods. I'm wondering how to synchronise the two functions, and whether there's another way to implement drawer-like View in SwiftUI. You could clone the repository [here](http://github.com/toto-minai/DVD-Player-Components). Thanks for your patient.